# Lists traversal in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

myList is a list with elements both as symbols or lists of the same type of myList.
For example: myList = '(a b (a d c) d ()) , etc.

I want to write a function in Scheme which would just traverse it (eventually I will replace the symbols with other values).

I wrote this function:

```
(define traversal (lambda (myList)
       (if (null? myList) '()
           (if (and (list? (car myList)) (not (null? (car myList))))
               (list (traversal (car myList)) (traversal (cdr myList)))
               ; else if car is an empty list
               (if (null?  (car myList))
                   (list (traversal (cdr myList)))
                   ; else car is a symbol
                   (append (list (car myList)) (traversal (cdr myList))))))))
```

It gives correct results for some configuration of myList, but definitely it is not the one.
For example,

```
(display (traversal '((f) h (r t b) (x m b m y) b (c (d)))))
```

adds additional paranthesis which I don't need.

What would be a correct way to display such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're testing `null?` in so many places, where one test is generally enough.
2. You rarely use `list` in these traversals, but simply `cons`.
3. Also, `append` is best avoided, and not needed here.
4. Repetitive use of `(car ...)` is optimised with a `let` form.

The simplified form of your code would be:

```
(define traversal 
  (lambda (myList)
    (if (null? myList) 
        '()
        (let ((c (car myList)))
          (cons (if (list? c) (traversal c) c)
                (traversal (cdr myList)))))))
```

**EDIT**

While this procedure works well for proper lists, it doesn't correctly work for improper lists (although it appears to). The following is a more general approach that works for every kind of [S-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression), including proper lists, and I recommend this over the previous code:

```
(define traversal
  (lambda (sexp)
    (cond
      ((null? sexp) '())
      ((pair? sexp) (cons (traversal (car sexp))
                          (traversal (cdr sexp))))
      (else          sexp))))
```

Comment: Since you're using `list?`, wouldn't `first` and `rest` be preferred rather than  `car` and `cdr`? (Since it's obviously `#!racket` code)

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution. Here are a few hints:

Instead of nested `if`s try using the `cond` form, it is more readable.

The expression `(and (list? (car myList)) (not (null? (car myList))))` is correct, but you may use `(pair? (car myList))` which is shorter and does almost the same thing.

`traversal` should return a list but using `list` with list arguments here
`(list (traversal (car myList)) (traversal (cdr myList)))`
will return a list of lists. E.g. `(list '(a) '(b))` will return `((a) (b))` instead of `(a b)`. In these cases you should use `append` `(append '(a) '(b))` -> `(a b)`.

If a value is not a list but you want to add it to an existing list, use the `cons` procedure.
`(cons 'a '(b c))` -> `(a b c)`.